# Understanding WPScan results and how to fix vulnerabilities

Tags: wordpress, security

I have this vulnerabilities

```
[!] Title: sitepress-multilingual-cms - Full Path Disclosure
    Reference: https://wpvulndb.com/vulnerabilities/6104
[i] Fixed in: 3.1.7.2
```

,

```
[!] Title: WPML <= 3.1.7.2 - Multiple Vulnerabilities (Including SQLi)
    Reference: https://wpvulndb.com/vulnerabilities/7843
    Reference: http://seclists.org/bugtraq/2015/Mar/60
    Reference: http://wpml.org/2015/03/wpml-security-update-bug-and-fix/
    Reference: http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/130810/
    Reference: http://klikki.fi/adv/wpml.html
    Reference: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-2314
    Reference: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-2791
    Reference: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-2792
    Reference: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/36414/
[i] Fixed in: 3.1.9
```

and

```
    [!] Title: WPML 2.9.3-3.2.6 - Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) in Accept-Language Header
    Reference: https://wpvulndb.com/vulnerabilities/8173
    Reference: http://blog.secupress.fr/en/xss-wpml-header-405.html
[i] Fixed in: 3.2.7
```

According the the report they all sould be fixed fro version  3.2.7 but I have version 3.9.4 and still get that results

This are my current versions:

[image]

So how should I get rid of them?

Comment: You should ask WPML Support, not the community. Or much better, switch the product if the support will not help.

Comment: Not familiar with this scanner. Guessing it reads files on disk. Do you have the old version on disk somewhere that it might be reading from? Or, is it possible that you are running the vulnerable version and don't know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan here. One of the WPScan developers.

It looks as though WPScan could not detect the installed plugin version. When this happens, WPScan will show a warning, and then output all known vulnerabilities for that plugin. This is to allow the user to do their own investigation, rather than potentially causing a False Negative result.

If you look back through the WPScan output, you should see a warning that says:

> We could not determine a version so all vulnerabilities are printed
>   out

Answer (score 0):

Although wpscan is a very handy tool, it still considered a (community one); the more accurate results about the vulnerability and remediation shall require [Developer subscription to API](https://wpscan.com/api)
,After generating you key you can use it

```
$ wpscan --url http://wordpress.target.site.com --api-token TOKEN
```

Remember that you can subscribe for developer plan for a free and benefit from the advanced features with limited number of API daily request.